# Which disks does "sync" synchronize?

Tags: disk, synchronization

The man page of *sync* can be found on [die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sync).

I wonder if it only synchronizes the disk of my *current working directory (cwd)* or all disks?

The man page does not say anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sync` utility is mostly a wrapper around [the `sync` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html); the manual page for the latter says

> `sync()` causes all pending modifications to filesystem metadata
> and cached file data to be written to the underlying filesystems.

All pending changes are written, across all devices.

The manual page you found is somewhat outdated; `sync` also supports explicitly writing a specific file or file system, and you can see that in [more recent versions of the manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sync.1.html). So the answer to your question is “all disks” by default, but it can be finer-grained if you specify additional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As the manpage says,

> `sync` writes any data buffered in memory out to disk.

Therefore it writes to any disk for which there are pending writes. So the answer to your question is: all disks.